# Can anyone explain the exact difference between panic and error and when to use each in go, with examples?

Tags: go

I am researching the difference between panic and error for a long time but unfortunately I haven't found the exact answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you read https://gobyexample.com/panic?

Comment: I'm not sure why anybody would downvote a question like that. If you know something, you should answer, not criticise.

Comment: Also see [Effective Go: Errors](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors)

Answer (score -1):

Think of it like this:

`panic()` (a verb) is an action

`error` (a noun) is an entity

Once you have an `error`, you can do something with it (`panic()`ing is just one of many options here, others being ignoring the error, returning the error to the caller or taking some other error specific action)

Note that you don't necessarily need an `error` to `panic()`.

Answer (score -2):

you can compare them with `Exception`, `Error` it's just `Exception` object, but `panic(err)` it's `throw exceptionObject`

Comment: I totally disagree with that error and exception are not comparable. In Go an error is a value, you can do whatever you want with it. An exception is only "catchable".

Comment: exceptions are values in most languages, it's just not idiomatic to return them in other languages.  I don't think it's a crazy comparison (maybe not an awesome one, but not crazy)